# drop duplicates pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am getting an error message when using drop_duplicates to drop duplicate columns from my dataframe.

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

Below is a min example (notice that I don't have duplicate column names here, since that column won't be added then, so I var1 would be called var0 in my actual dataframe)

```
dict1 = [{'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 2},
         {'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 4},
         {'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 8},
         {'var0':0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 12},]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=['s1', 's2','s1','s2'])
df.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

Comment: what version of pandas are you using. on `0.23.0` the above runs with error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your indexing, when you transpose your DataFrame you will get duplicate column names which are messing it up. See below

```
dict1 = [{'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 2},
         {'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 4},
         {'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 8},
         {'var0':0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 12},]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=['s1', 's2','s1','s2'])
df.reset_index().T.drop_duplicates().T.set_index('index')
```

Comment: Very nice, that worked on the min example. On my actual datframe (where I also have duplicate indexes I get this error: 
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: You may modify default recursion depth which is 1000 using `sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)`; not to mention that you will need to `import sys` too

Comment: ahhh very nice. Thank you so much, this worked!!!! I appreciate your help Massoud.