# Convert pandas Dataframe to numeric

Tags: python, pandas, numeric

My dataframe appears to be non-numeric after some transformations (see previous post on dropping duplicates: [drop duplicates pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470071/drop-duplicates-pandas-dataframe))

When I use it in a statsmodels regression I get this error:

ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).

Can I convert the entire dataframe back to numeric somehow?

Using the dataframe with sklearn works for some reason

I am actually not sure what the data type is, only after opening the dataframe in spyder I noticed that it is not colered anymore. When I used type(df) it just tells me that it is a dataframe.

This is an example from the post I mentioned where the transformation occurs (compare the df before and after the last line):

```
  dict1 = [{'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 2},
     {'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 4},
     {'var0': 0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 8},
     {'var0':0, 'var1': 0, 'var2': 12},]


 df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=['s1', 's2','s1','s2'])
```

df.reset_index().T.drop_duplicates().T.set_index('index')

This is the dataframe before running the last line:

```
 df.info()
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 Index: 4 entries, s1 to s2
 Data columns (total 3 columns):
 var0    4 non-null int64
 var1    4 non-null int64
 var2    4 non-null int64
 dtypes: int64(3)
```

And this is after:

```
  df.info()
  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
  Index: 4 entries, s1 to s2 
  Data columns (total 2 columns):
  var0    4 non-null object
  var2    4 non-null object
  dtypes: object(2)
  memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
```

After the transformation:

```
   print(df)
  var0 var2
  index          
 s1       0    2
 s2       0    4
 s1       0    8
 s2       0   12
```

Comment: I assume you are passing a string column into your statsmodel methods, could you provide us with a few rows of your dataframe as an example?

Comment: Actually, the example from the post I mentioned (see link) illustrates this. Once the transformation is applied, the dataframe seems to be in string format (or contains string format).

Comment: I answered your previous question too. In that question all data was of type int64; I think your actual dataframe is somehow different than this.

Comment: oh yeah, I remember Massoud. But notice how something changes with this min example. When I open it before and after (the last line in the code you provided) in spyder, the coloring of the dataframe is white rather than red.

Comment: I don't know about Jupyter, try `print(df.info())` before and after transformation. All data types are int64. Even when I use `np.asarray(df)` on your min example all I get are integers.

Comment: I have added the output above from df.info(). It says the dtype is object after the transformation

Comment: As the answer to this post, you may use .astype to convert them back to int, but I am curious to see how your output is different than mine. Would you update your post with `print(df)` after transformation?

Comment: @MassoudHosseinali, I tested our transform, and it converts to `object` for me as well. the reason being the transpose step where `s1` is placed in the same column as the ints. this forces them all to be objects, and when transposed back, pandas doesn't know to convert back to int

Comment: Massoud, I have added the print(df) output above. Haleemur's solution below worked .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue with the original answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470071/drop-duplicates-pandas-dataframe) is that the transformation converts the integers to objects. This happens after the transpose since now the same column stores integers as well as the index which is textual.

Instead, you can sidestep the issue like this:

```
out = df.reset_index(drop=True).T.drop_duplicates().T.set_index(df.index)
out
    var0  var2
s1     0     2
s2     0     4
s1     0     8
s2     0    12
```

Or, if your *actual* example is sufficiently different that you can't use the above, there is always casting, i.e.

```
out.astype(int)
```

Comment: Yes, this worked!!! Thank you so much, I will keep the casting option in mind for other cases in the future. Thank you both for your help!!!